# Hall of fame data corrupted without MissingNo? Pokemon Stadium can't find saved files

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-stadium

I have Pokemon Blue (French version) I got 151 pkmn by catching / trading (MissingNo doesn't work in French version) the hall of fame data is still glitched and Pokémon Stadium can't find my save, why?

I also have American Red version (in which I used MissingNo and I don't have the hall of fame) and Pokemon Stadium can't find the save too!

Help please.